# How to split string into columns in java

Tags: java, regex, talend

I am parsing file which has following type of rows using Talend, i have tried tFileInputDelimted component to parse it, but text en-closer "'" not working.

```
1, 0, 1, 73, 0, 'root.1', 'Root Asset', '{"site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core":{"6":1}}'
```

I need a output in following format.

```
1
0
1
73
0
root.1
Root Asset
{"site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core":{"6":1}}
```

Edited: Sample row

```
`90, 'Loader Menu', '', '<div class="arrowlistmenu">\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/ordersoncalendar">View Orders</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/reportmaster/?task=report_details">Time Sheets</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/availabilitycalendar?task=availability">Update Availability</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/workers?task=update_personal_info">Update Personal Information</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><strong><a href="index.php/component/workers?task=ask_password_change">Change Password</a></strong></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n</div>', 1, 'loader-menu-position', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, 'mod_custom', 2, 1, '{"prepare_content":"1","backgroundimage":"","layout":"_:default","moduleclass_sfx":"","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"static"}', 0, '*'`
```

and output expected for this row is.

`90
'Loader Menu'
''
'<div class="arrowlistmenu">\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/ordersoncalendar">View Orders</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/reportmaster/?task=report_details">Time Sheets</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/availabilitycalendar?task=availability">Update Availability</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><a href="index.php/component/workers?task=update_personal_info">Update Personal Information</a></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n<h3 class="menuheader"><strong><a href="index.php/component/workers?task=ask_password_change">Change Password</a></strong></h3>\r\n<div class="shrink_div"> </div>\r\n</div>'
1
'loader-menu-position'
0
'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
'0000-00-00 00:00:00'
1
'mod_custom'
2
1
'{"prepare_content":"1","backgroundimage":"","layout":"_:default","moduleclass_sfx":"","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"static"}'
0
'*'`

As I said file has millions of rows it is very difficult to put all the formats of rows here but at least we get some thing which can parse above lines then that is also acceptable. 
please suggest how can I achieve it, as this file has millions of records.

Comment: Consider using a proper CSV parser and avoid complex regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\\s*,\\s*(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD9cK8/6)

Comment: This works very well but when my input comes like this it fails. edited the same question and added more details.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/mD9cK8/7) is not expected? update your question with expected output too..

Comment: Ok I am adding more scenarios so it will be better parse.

Comment: your previous solution working fine with first sample row but it comes to the second row it fails.

Comment: ya right. let me test for some more time before closing this issue, thank you very much for your help great skill.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it contains only strings and integers. So you could do matching.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'|(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```